# Hiding divs whenever a new one opens

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a website with two options represented by `<a>` tags, chairs and tables. This is the HTML that displays the div whenever a `<a>` tag is clicked on.

```
<div id="workbench_menu">
                <p><strong>Living Room</strong></p>
                <a onclick="chairs()" href="#"><p>chairs</p></a>
                <a onclick="tables()" href="#"><p>tables</p></a>
            </div>
            <div id="workbench_objects">

                <div id="tables" class="refresh" style="display:none;">
                    <div class="workbench_object_info">
                        <img src="images/house/objects/table_4.png">
                        <p>20 oak logs</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id="chairs" class="refresh" style="display:none;">
                    <div class="workbench_object_info">
                        <img src="images/house/objects/stonechair_1.png">
                        <p>20 oak logs</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
```

The javascript which handles that function is here:

```
           <script>
                function tables() {
                    document.getElementsByClassName('refresh').style.display='none';
                    document.getElementById('tables').style.display='inline';
                }
                function chairs() {
                    document.getElementsByClassName('refresh').style.display='none';
                    document.getElementById('chairs').style.display='inline';
                }
            </script>
```

So what I am trying to do, is that when one of the options are pressed, everything else is hidden and only the div that is assigned that specific `<a>` tag will be displayed. When a new `<a>` tag is clicked, the old one will be hidden and the new on will be displayed.

I have tried adding a `document.getElementsByClassName('refresh').style.display='none';` in hope that every class with "refresh" attached to it, will be put on `display:none` but this does not work somehow. The outcome is that after a link is clicked, the div is shown. After a new link is clicked, that div is shown too without hiding the old div. Hope you have some suggetions, thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

```
var length = document.getElementsByClassName('refresh').length;
                for(var i=0; i<length;i++){
                    document.getElementsByClassName('refresh')[i].style.display='none';
                }
                function tables() {
                    document.getElementById('tables').style.display='inline';
                }
                function chairs() {
                    document.getElementById('chairs').style.display='inline';
                }
```

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName('refresh') returns an array of elements.So you should iterate on returned array and set display none for each element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

document.getElementsByClassName('refresh') will return you the array of elements.

```
function tables() {
      hideElements();
      document.getElementById('tables').style.display='inline';
  }
  function chairs() {
      hideElements();
      document.getElementById('chairs').style.display='inline';
  }
  function hideElements(){
    var length = document.getElementsByClassName('refresh').length;
    for(var i=0; i<length;i++){
        document.getElementsByClassName('refresh')[i].style.display='none';
    }
  }
```

Comment: Should I do it like above? Because that makes no difference hmm, check my update

Comment: It still does not hide the div elements, but I have one question, do you think it is because all the inner divs of that div, needs a `refresh` class too?